# NodeJS - How to pass a mysql connection from main to child process?

Tags: mysql, node.js, child-process

I tried the following server+worker code but it simply did not work.

server.js:

```
var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cp = require('child_process');

var serverPort=20460;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    database : 'test',
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : ''
});

var server = net.createServer(function (socket){
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log("Server received: ",data);
        var child = cp.fork('./worker');
        child.send({'connection': connection});
    });
});

connection.connect(function(err, two){
    if (!err) {
        server.listen(serverPort);
    }
});
```

worker.js:

```
process.on('message', function(obj) {
    //Will add more code to it later...
    console.log("CHILD::Received: ",obj);
});
```

Gives me the following error at the child process' console.log():

```
JSON.stringify, avoid TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I would not do this.  There's no good reason to bottleneck your clustered app on one connection, and likewise there are very good reasons (scalability) for not doing so.  Pass the configuration information down, configure your MySQL instance to allow multiple open connections and have each process manage its own connection.

Comment: What is the best I could (should) create a connection for each worker, everytime they receive a message? By the way, if it is relevant, each worker will only receive a message, handle it, insert important data into a mysql table and then die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do it is to have worker.js be the real "app" and the server.js just sets up the clustering. I've not tested this, but something along the lines of this:

```
// worker.js    
var connection = require('./db');
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket){
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log("Server received: ",data);
        connection.connect();
        connection.query(/* your query here for inserting data */);
        connection.end();
    });
});

// db.js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var serverPort=20460;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    database : 'test',
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : ''
});
module.exports = connection;

// server.js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  require('./worker');
}
```

For bonus points, you could use something like node-pool to create a connection pool, and have the db module return a connection from the pool instead.

Comment: Hi. I actually changed the structure of my code BUT, your code just gave me a new perspective and I might try to follow your thoughts here and implement it this way... Just a couple doubts I have: 1-  When you `require('./worker')` for the non-master cluster forks, does that make them load that worker.js file and create the server (like as if they were a sum of both server+worker.js) ? 2- Any advantages of making "cluster-workers" instead of "child-process workers"?

Comment: Well, so I guess I missed mentioning one thing.  require will load the module and run any code in it. If you have more than one, it'll draw from the module cache rather than executing the code again. So in the scenario I was describing, you'd actually want to export a function, then call that function (which does the work of setting up the socket, etc) in the master file.  The advantage of using cluster is that it does the child process management for you, including restarting dead child processes and wiring up inter-process communication for you.

Comment: By the way, where should the line `server.listen(serverPort)` appear in your code? I just noticed it lacks this part...